# How to set get_the_excerpt() limit word in shordcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want limit words in shortcode. I'm  trying to made a WP plugin here i need limited words from get_the_excerpt{(); functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to tell exactly what you are asking; could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has so many ways :
Place this in functions.php:

```
function excerpt($num) {
    $limit = $num+1;
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)."... (<a href='" .get_permalink($post->ID) ." '>Read more</a>)";
    echo $excerpt;
}
```

Then, in your theme, use the code `<?php excerpt('22'); ?>` to limit the excerpt to 22 characters.

Other way : `<?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,30); ?>`

enjoy!!

Answer (score 11):

you should use official WordPress function:

```
$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null );
```

Answer (score 0):

The same question has been answered on [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69436/excerpt-in-characters) by [Nicolai](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/22534/nicolai)

Answer:

```
function kzmagazine_get_excerpt( $count ){
   $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );

   $excerpt = get_the_content(); // or get_the_excerpt();
   $excerpt = strip_tags( $excerpt );
   $excerpt = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $count );
   $excerpt = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, strripos( $excerpt, " " ) );
   $excerpt = rtrim( $excerpt, ",.;:- _!$&#" );
   $excerpt = $excerpt . '<a href="'.$permalink.'" style="text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;(...)</a>';

   return $excerpt;
}
```